# xamarin navigate from one fragment to another

Tags: android, fragment, xamarin.android

I am trying to navigate from on fragment to another by click a button in original fragment. How ever I got a Exception

[Image of exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqiLk.png)

[Image of my code for the original Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7OWN.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a Layout in your call of transaction.Replace(), instead you should pass the Id the of the ViewGroup where the fragment will be inserted in your layout.

so the layout of the activity containing your fragments should look something like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

And in your FragmentStockSearch fragment, override OnCreateView to something like this:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.your_layout, null, false);
}
```

and finally your fragment transaction code:

```
var trans = new FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
trans.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, new FragmentStockSearch(), "FragmentStockSearch");
trans.AddToBackStack(null);
trans.Commit();
```